# Set and get methods not working properly

Tags: java, android

I am having `MyFragment` class which receives intents from broadcast -

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.DEPARTURE_TIME)){
                Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
                if (args != null) {

                     departure_time = args.getInt("Departure");
                    Log.d("hi","vehicle viv0" + departure_time);

                   setDepTime(departure_time);
                }
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.ARRIVAL_TIME)){
                Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
                if (args != null) {
                     arrival_time = args.getInt("Arrival");
                    Log.d("hi","vehicle viv1" + arrival_time);

                  setArrivalTime(arrival_time);
                }
            }
        }
    };

  //public method to set the time variable
    public void setArrivalTime(int arrival_time){
        Log.d("hi","vehicle viv2" + arrival_time);
        this.arrival_time = arrival_time;
        Log.d("hi","vehicle viv3" + this.arrival_time);
    }

    //public method to set the time variable
    public void setDepTime(int departure_time){
        this.departure_time = departure_time;
    }

    public int getArrivalTime(){
        Log.d("hi","vehicle viv5" + this.arrival_time);
        return this.arrival_time;
    }

    public int getDepTime(){
        return this.departure_time;
    }
```

I am setting the value of arrival_time and departure_time as above. Now from `MyOwn` class, I am doing these -

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..........
    Button okButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myxml);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   MyFragment mFragment = new MyFragment();
                    int depi = mFragment.getDepTime();
                 }
            });

            MyFragment mFragment = new StopListFragment();
            int arri = mFragment.getArrivalTime();
            Log.d("hi","vehicle viv6" + arri);
    }
```

When I use `getArrivalTime()`, I am getting `0`. The logs are -

```
D/hi: vehicle viv1 = 13012
D/hi: vehicle viv2 = 13012
D/hi: vehicle viv3 = 13012
D/hi: vehicle viv5 = 0
D/hi: vehicle viv6 = 0
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since "MyOwn" Class creates a new object of the Fragment, then the default initialized value of variable 'arrival_time' will be returned.

Comment: Ok how do I pass the fragment object instance then to MyOwn class

Comment: try making the arrival_time & departure_time as 'static'.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getDepTime() on a new instance of the fragment, which obviously does not have any data since you just created it

Comment: Oh... So how do I do this?

Comment: is your onCreateDialog method inside the fragment?

Comment: onCreateDialog is in MyOwn Class... it is not a fragment class

Comment: Which kind of class is MyOwn class? is it an activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFragment mFragment = new MyFragment();

 @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ..........
        Button okButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myxml);
                okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int depi = mFragment.getDepTime();
                     }
                });

                int arri = mFragment.getArrivalTime();
                Log.d("hi","vehicle viv6" + arri);
        }
```

You use setter and getter on a different **objects** of the class. Try to exclude your fragment initialization out to the global value and see how it works. See example above.